# Delete portion of browser in WatiN

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, xpath, watin

I am using WatiN to go through a website page by page using an iterative loop going from page 1-10 then clicking the right arrow to go on, etc.    example: Page:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

I am using:

browser.Link(Find.ByText(i.ToString())).Click();
doc.LoadHtml(browser.Html);

The problem I am facing is that there is a sidebar with 'Refine search' that has links with the same text of '2' , '3', '4', etc. So instead of clicking the page number up top, WatiN is clicking the first Link with that text, which ruins my results.

Is there a way in WatiN to delete a portion of the browser, like a sidebar, header, etc, so that it only loads the main table that I want? And then load the browser into the Document afterwards?

Or any other suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Look at refining your selection.  Something more like `broswer.Div("theDivIDwithPageNumbers").Link(Find.ByText).....`    You can also use multiple selectors like `Link(Find.ByText("blah") && Find.ByIndex(3)).Click();`

I'd highly recommend the first approach of trying to define it more explicitly than by index or something else relative.  Combining explicit declaration AND using Page classes is very nice.  And if none of this is making sense regarding page structure / paths / etc, read up on all the above and tinker around with the IE F12 tools and/or Firebug in Firefox.